# How to stop Google translation on a link?

Tags: google, email, translation

I use Mailchimp for campaigns. They have a feature where a person that receives the email can click the email in a web browser and translate to another language.  The issue is the links in the email to my website change my website into the user's choice language. This creates an issue with my maps on my website not displaying. How can I get Google translations not to translate my website when they click the links in the web browser email?

Comment: Try adding this to the head section of your HTML:  `<meta name="google" content="notranslate">` as per Google's documentation [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812).

Comment: I still cannot get it to work. I added the url with the translation in Spanish. Once you click link and go on my website,  the top map pointer is distorted and the map at the bottom of the webpage will not show.


http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=auto&langpair=auto|es&u=https%3A%2F%2Fus15.campaign-archive.com%2F%3Fe%3D%5BUNIQID%5D%26u%3Deac502b28d36ca31cdf5171c8%26id%3D1af5808db2

Comment: In Google Chrome, there didn't appear to be any difference between the translated page and the original - only the text changed, the maps showed for both and nothing was distorted...perhaps this appears in a particular browser? You can try wrapping whatever you don't want Google to translate in a span like this:  `<span class="notranslate">Don't translate this</span>`. You can't prevent a user from using Google translate on your site however, or any other translator. If it's a major issue for you, then perhaps you can add a link for English.